# Postgresql 9.4: How to find out the stack level of nested function

Tags: postgresql, functions

Here are the two cases:

- Function fA fetches some rows and returns a table
- Function fB calls function fA and returns a table

Within fA, how could I know whether it's been called from the program or by fB?

Is there some @@nestlevel that can count how deep in the stack are the functions running?

Big thank you in advance,

Comment: I'm not aware of any good way to do this. Access to the call stack via `GET DISAGNOSTICS` has been discussed and may be implemented for 9.6. Ask on pgsql-general and suggest it as a feature - or even better, implement it and send in a patch to plpgsql.

Answer (score 1):

There's a different, simpler, solution for this. Add an argument to function `fA` with a default value, for instance: `called_from_b BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE`. Then, provide that argument when calling `fA` from `fB`.

I understand that this doesn't directly answer your question, but it does provide a solution for the example usecase that you provide.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, this is now possible (and easy) in all currently supported PostgreSQL versions, thanks to [`GET DIAGNOSTICS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS):

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TYPE stuff AS (
    nestlevel int
    ,arbitrary text
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fa()
    RETURNS stuff
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
DECLARE
  _stack text;
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS _stack = PG_CONTEXT;

    RETURN ROW(
        array_length(string_to_array(_stack, E'\n'), 1) - 1,
        'Some text'
    )::stuff;
END;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fb()
    RETURNS stuff
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN fa();
END;
$$;

SELECT fa();
SELECT fb();

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

```
BEGIN
CREATE TYPE
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
       fa
-----------------
 (0,"Some text")
(1 row)

       fb
-----------------
 (1,"Some text")
(1 row)

ROLLBACK
```